# regex to parse csv

Tags: asp.net, regex, csv

I'm looking for a regex that will parse a line at a time from a csv file.  basically, what string.readline() does, but it will allow line breaks if they are within double quotes.

or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand why people are obsessed with regular expressions on Stack Overflow. I understand their utility, but I don't see why you can't just use a CSV parser.

Comment: There are so many 3rd party CSV parsing libraries out and none of them uses regex. Just because that isn't the *right tool* for it.

Comment: I understand completely, because it offers the lure of an easy fix. If you don't know regex well, it sometimes seems like any text processing problem can be solved in a single line of regex. Whereas finding, hooking up, and testing a parser can seem intimidating by comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression (C#) For CSV by RFC 4180](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132392/regular-expression-c-for-csv-by-rfc-4180)

Answer (score 5):

Using regex to parse CSV is fine for simple applications in well-controlled CSV data, but there are often so many **gotchas**, such as **escaping for embedded quotes and commas in quoted strings**, etc.   This often makes regex tricky and risky for this task.

I recommend a well-tested CSV module for your purpose.

--Edit:-- See this excellent article, [Stop Rolling Your Own CSV Parser!](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)

Answer (score 1):

The **FileHelpers** library is pretty good for this purpose.

http://www.filehelpers.net/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on error prone regular expressions, over simpified "split" logic or 3rd party components, use the .NET framework's built in functionality:

```
Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\MyFile.csv")

    Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited

    Dim MyDelimeters(0 To 0) As String
    Reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = False
    Reader.SetDelimiters(","c)

    Dim currentRow As String()
    While Not Reader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
            Dim currentField As String
            For Each currentField In currentRow
                MsgBox(currentField)
            Next
        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
            "is not valid and will be skipped.")
        End Try
    End While
End Using
```