# Regex to to parse csv with nested quotes

Tags: regex, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, regular expressions : how to parse comma-separated values, where some values might be quoted strings themselves containing commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189416/c-regular-expressions-how-to-parse-comma-separated-values-where-some-values)
>   [regex to parse csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611409/regex-to-parse-csv)

I know this question has asked many time, but there were different answers; I am confused.

My row is:

```
1,3.2,BCD,"qwer 47"" ""dfg""",1
```

The optionally quoting and double quoting MS Excel standard. (The data: `qwer 47" "dfg"` is represented like this `"qwer 47"" ""dfg"""`.)

I need a regex.

Comment: Seriously.. Provide some desired output. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: this is a row out of my csv, which i need to validate or match

Comment: the data: qwer 47" "dfg" is represent like this "qwer 47"" ""dfg""" (MS excel standard)

Comment: I think the intention is clear, but why use a regex and not a CSV parser?

Comment: But what are you trying to do? You need to specify which values are acceptable and which aren't.

Comment: so it mean that if cell has double quotes in between, it will start with quote as well and all inner quotes will be escaped by applying 2double quotes for 1.

Comment: We should have @Community automatically downvote questions that have ([tag:regex], [tag:csv]) or ([tag:regex], [tag:html]). :P

Comment: @TimPietzcker When I did the comment the question was totally different.

Comment: see the whole idea is validate the whole row at once, rather than a cell at once. yes, in case the value is string type then it should start and end with quote, any quotes in between should be escaped by putting 2 quotes instead of one.

Comment: Regex is used to validate data, do you need to change certain cells (i.e. add quotes if there aren't any)? Because that calls for a parser

Comment: So should your third value also be in quotes ("BCD")? As it is a string...

Comment: The language is Java. What I am trying to do is validating a row(specifying what values are acceptable and which aren't)

Comment: no BCD should not be in quotes as the there is not inner double quotes in it.

Comment: So only a value that has inner quotes should also start and end with quotes? And the inner quotes should be doubled - is this the goal?

Comment: yes! I just need to validate this

Comment: Do you NEED to use regex? Because with regex on a whole row, I don't think this can be done. A simple bit of code could do it though.

Comment: my whole row is just a string, so wanted to apply regex to it.

Comment: okay i am going to post an answer, see if it fits what you are trying to do

Comment: regex is not the best way to solve this problem. A simple parser will do a better job. See the answer in the dupe question quoted.

Answer (score 7):

OK, you've seen from the comments that regex is *so* not the right tool for this. But if you insist, here goes:

This regex will work in Java (or .NET and other implementations that support possessive quantifiers and verbose regexes):

```
^            # Start of string
(?:          # Match the following:
 (?:         #  Either match
  [^",\n]*+  #   0 or more characters except comma, quote or newline
 |           #  or
  "          #   an opening quote
  (?:        #   followed by either
   [^"]*+    #    0 or more non-quote characters
  |          #   or
   ""        #    an escaped quote ("")
  )*         #   any number of times
  "          #   followed by a closing quote
 )           #  End of alternation
 ,           #  Match a comma (separating the CSV columns)
)*           # Do this zero or more times.
(?:          # Then match
 (?:         #  using the same rules as above
  [^",\n]*+  #  an unquoted CSV field
 |           #  or a quoted CSV field
  "(?:[^"]*+|"")*"
 )           #  End of alternation
)            # End of non-capturing group
$            # End of string
```

Java code:

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches(
    "(?x)^         # Start of string\n" +
    "(?:           # Match the following:\n" +
    " (?:          #  Either match\n" +
    "  [^\",\\n]*+ #   0 or more characters except comma, quote or newline\n" +
    " |            #  or\n" +
    "  \"          #   an opening quote\n" +
    "  (?:         #   followed by either\n" +
    "   [^\"]*+    #    0 or more non-quote characters\n" +
    "  |           #   or\n" +
    "   \"\"       #    an escaped quote (\"\")\n" +
    "  )*          #   any number of times\n" +
    "  \"          #   followed by a closing quote\n" +
    " )            #  End of alternation\n" +
    " ,            #  Match a comma (separating the CSV columns)\n" +
    ")*            # Do this zero or more times.\n" +
    "(?:           # Then match\n" +
    " (?:          #  using the same rules as above\n" +
    "  [^\",\\n]*+ #  an unquoted CSV field\n" +
    " |            #  or a quoted CSV field\n" +
    "  \"(?:[^\"]*+|\"\")*\"\n" +
    " )            #  End of alternation\n" +
    ")             # End of non-capturing group\n" +
    "$             # End of string");
```

Be aware that you can't assume that every line in a CSV file is a complete row. You can have newlines within a CSV row (as long as the column containing the newlines is enclosed in quotes). This regex knows this, but it will fail if you feed it only a partial row. Which is yet another reason why you really need a CSV parser to validate a CSV file. That's what parsers do. If you control your input and know that you'll never have newlines inside a CSV field, you might get away with it, but only then.

Comment: how to read the CSV fields with this regex?

Comment: In my experience, this type of regex may end up in catastrophic backtracking http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html and crash your system. This is the case if you are missing the last quote of a quoted string (i.e. csv line is truncated / corrupted)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done Java in a while, so here's a pseudocode to do this. You could use this as a function that accepts a String representing a row of your csv.

```
1. Split the row by "'" delimiter into an array of strings. (method might be called string.split())
2. Iterate through the array (cells).
    3. If the current string (cell) contains a double quote:
        4. If it doesn't start with a quote - return false; else remove that quote
        5. If it doesn't end with a quote - return false; else remove that quote
        6. Iterate through the remaining characters of the string
            7. If a quote is found, check if the next character is also a quote - if it is not - return false
        7. End character iteration
    8. End if
9. End array iteration
10. Return true
```

Comment: hi niko, this what i was trying to avoid. I want it be validated in one shot

Comment: regex is hardly a "one shot" - it is very likely to be more expensive than this code. And if you need a one-liner, use it as a method you would call. Do you have restrictions on code length or similar?

Comment: according to my understanding regex are faster in string parsing

Comment: For a complex regex such as you require it's pretty much guaranteed to be slower than a specialized coded solution. Regex still has to iterate through the string, and has to iterate through itself and use complex rules to match patterns. In this code we aren't really matching anything - we are looking for a specific character. Regex would be an overkill.

Comment: This fails where there is a comma within quotes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use regexp from this blog article which is about the same problem you are trying to solve.

See it here: http://www.kimgentes.com/worshiptech-web-tools-page/2008/10/14/regex-pattern-for-parsing-csv-files-with-embedded-commas-dou.html

In short `^(("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*)(,("(?:[^"]|"")*"|[^,]*))*)$`

Comment: i had gone through it, can you explain a bit.

Comment: This is not correct. It allows strings like `"lkj"""lkjlkj""""""` and many others that should not be matched.

Comment: You are right, thanks. I use it for parsing (so it doesn't matter), he needs validation.