# How to Split my String in Javascript for special case

Tags: javascript, regex, split

i want my string using "," (comma) but my String have some special case please help me

```
input : a,"d,e,f",g //string in csv`

     var myarray=str.spilt(",");
```

output: `myarray[0] = a ,myarray[1]="d ,myarray[3]=e,myarray[4]=f.....`

required output : `myarray[0] =a ,myarray[1]="d,e,f",myarray[2] = g`

please help me... 
thanks

Comment: Is `"a,"d,e,f",g"` really the string?

Comment: What is the source of your string?  I think you would need a parser for the general case to handle this.

Comment: its field from csv file

Comment: field from csv => 704-wew-9494,"ds daf 787, erwerwe, NC 28134",,,,4/22/2013,5/1/2017,,0

Comment: I would use a csv parser like [papaparse](http://papaparse.com/) or any other parser. Those take care of the various csv formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small non regex, iterative and slow approach:

```
var result = [], tmp="", inString = false;
str.split("").forEach(function(char){
  inString = inString != (char === '"');
   if( !inString && char === "," ){
     result.push(tmp);
     tmp = "";
    }else{
     tmp+=char;
    }
});
result.push(tmp);
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/zipikedeta/edit?console)

You may also use a regular for loop instead of the forEach:

```
for(char of str){ /*...*/ }
```

However, thats up to you.

Comment: I still dont get why people downvote without saying whats wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

This would be a lot smoother with a mapcat operator in JS.

```
let input = 'a,"d,e,f",g'
var result = []
input.split('"').forEach((e, i) => {
    result = result.concat( i % 2 == 0 ? e.split(',') : e )
})
result = result.filter(e => e != "")
```

As ChristianFigueroa pointed out: This won't work for cases where the quotes don't surround the whole field: `value,`**`val"ue"`**`, "value"`

However if that is not important for you:
[jsperf/speedtest](https://jsperf.com/questions-45649165)

Comment: This fails in a case where a quote is included in the value, bit isn't the first character. (eg value,val"ue,"value"). There's no rule saying a quote can't appear inside one of the values

Comment: Nice approach! But isnt the result rather splitted by *string / not string* ? e.g. "a+'b'"

Comment: The speedtest-link seems broken (HTTP status 500). May [replace by any alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695890/how-to-profile-javascript-now-that-jsperf-is-down).

Answer (score 1):

Strongly advise to parse [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example) with a tested **CSV-parser** library instead of any regex.

### CSV-parsers for JavaScript

Among the common ones example:

- [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/)
- [JQuery-CSV](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv)
- [D3.js DSV module](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/v3.0.1/README.md#csvParse), including a CSV parser

#### Example usages

Your example using

- .. [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/), can **auto-detect the delimiter** and has already a **default for quoted-strings**: `quoteChar: '"'` (like yours). [Try it online](https://www.papaparse.com/demo):

```
var csvInput = 'a,"d,e,f",g';
var results = Papa.parse(csvString);
console.log(results);
```

Output (copied from console):

```
{
  data: [
    "a",
    "d,e,f",
    "g"
  ],
  errors: []
  meta: {delimiter: ",", linebreak: "↵", aborted: false, truncated: false, cursor: 11}
}
```

- .. [JQuery-CSV](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv), you can [try it online](http://evanplaice.github.io/jquery-csv/examples/to-array.html):

```
var input = 'a,"d,e,f",g';
var result = $.csv.toArray(input);
console.log(result);

// even configurable
$.csv.toArrays(input, {
  delimiter: "\"", // already the default, custom value delimiter character
  separator: ',', // already the default, custom field separator character
});
```

Output:

```
[
  "a",
  "d,e,f",
  "g"
]
```

### Disadvantage of regular-expressions for CSV parsing

The regex for CSV-parsing can be either simple like `split(',')` or long, cumbersome and fragile - [catasrophic backracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) like described on regular-expressions.info: "A Real Example: Matching CSV Records".

Furthermore:

- a regex is not easy to configure.
- a regex is hard to document, maintain, modularize or extend.

If you still want to try, read

- Ben Nadel (2009): ["Ask Ben: Parsing CSV Strings With Javascript Exec() Regular Expression Command"](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-ask-ben-parsing-csv-strings-with-javascript-exec-regular-expression-command.htm)

### Related questions

- [Example JavaScript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/example-javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)
- [How can I parse a CSV string with JavaScript, which contains comma in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data)
- [Regex to to parse csv with nested quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947294/regex-to-to-parse-csv-with-nested-quotes)
- [How to read data From *.CSV file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431268/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `regexp`

```js
var str = 'a,"d,e,f",g';
console.log(str.split(/,"|",/));
```

Comment: This will only work for the special case where  `,"` or `",` will be the separater. But based on the comment, the OP is looking for a solution where the quoted column could appear at any place in the row.

Comment: when you ask why didn't you tell all cases

Comment: my answer is base on you argument

Comment: It was not me who wrote the question?

Comment: to someone who vote me down, it means my answer is incorrect

Comment: Can provide this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TOPups/1) link to test your regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
myarray = []
while (str) {
    start = str;
    str = str.replace(/(".*?"|[^",]+|)($|,)/, function(match, group1) {
        myarray.push(group1);
        return "";
    });
    if (str == start) break;
}
```

The code above goes through the CSV string, adding each value it can to the array `myarray`. If the value has a `"` as it's first character (may contain commas), it will match until it reaches the next closing `"`. Otherwise, the regex will just look for the next comma. If it finds something like a value without a closing `"`, it will automatically stop and `myarray` will include all the values up to that point that it failed. Empty values (two adjacent commas) will also work.

Comment: Does not work for longer rows like the example the OP wrote in the comments `704-wew-9494,"ds daf 787, erwerwe, NC 28134",,,,4/22/2013,5/1/2017,,0`

Comment: I added a comma in it so now it matches empty values correctly. Other than that it seems to work for me with the given string.

Answer (score -1):

You can clean up the CSV with adding delimiters " to create new columns. This is in excel though but I'm not sure how you parse this data so might not work for you. Or `str_replace()` them and then `str.split`?

Comment: How should a replace of the `"` work, if the result should be an array in the form `['a', 'd,e,f', 'g']`?